# Google's client id and client secret hardcoded in android application

Tags: security, oauth, hardcoded

I have an application that requires OAuth authentications for users and I have set the client id and secret client hardcoded of my project created in google console. If decompiling my app someone can see this values, what is the worst thing that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

You only want to authenticate requests from credible applications. If the client id and secret is stolen, you cannot guarantee this anymore. You cannot trust your communication partner. Never store this kind of sensible data on the device.

Comment: This answer is too general. And this guy ask if it is safe to put the OAuth within the source code with the awareness of reverse-engineering.

Comment: Why is this to general? He asks if it is safe and the answer is no.